# clonar funções array e objetos

Tags: javascript, array, orientação-a-objetos

Faça uma função para clonar arrays. (Dica: `clone = [ ...clone ]`)
Faça uma função para clonar objetos. (Dica: `clone = { ...objeto }`)

```
let total = 3, array1 = [1,2,3]


const clonar = () => {
     if (total === 0){
         console.log('clonado');
     }
}

console.log()
```

Comment: Qual é a sua dificuldade?

Comment: como pensar a lógica, não to conseguindo clonar

Comment: A dica já não é a própria resposta da pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria usar o [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`...`):

```
    var array1 = [1,2,3]
    var clone = [...array1]
```

A função que clona poderia ser assim:

```
    function clonaArray(array){
     var clone = [...array];
     return clone;
    }

    console.log(clonaArray(array1))
```